# Parallel.For loop - Assigning a unique data entity for each thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a 100 records for Parallelization, from 1 to 100, Now I can conveniently use a Parallel.For to execute them in Parallel as follows, which will work based on computing resources

```
 Parallel.For(0, limit, i =>
    {
        DoWork(i);
    });
```

but there are certain restrictions, each thread need to work with an identical Data entity and there are limited number of Data entities say 10, which are created in advanced by cloning each other and saving them in a structure like Dictionary or List. Now I can restrict the amount of parallelization using the following code:

```
 Parallel.For(0, limit, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
    {
        DoWork(i);
    });
```

But the issue is how to assign a unique data entity for each incoming thread, such that Data entity is not used by any other current thread in execution, since the number of threads and data entity are same, so starvation is not an issue. I can think of way, in which I create a boolean value for each data entity, specifying whether it's in use or not, thus we iterate through the dictionary or list to find the next available data entity and lock the overall assignment process, so that one thread is assigned a data entity at a given time, but in my view this issue will have much more elegant solution, my version is just a workaround, not really a fix. My logic is:

```
Parallel.For(0, limit, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
        {
            lock(All_Threads_Common_Object)
            {
              Check for available data entity using boolean
              Assign the Data entity
            }
            DoWork(i);

            Reset the Boolean value for another thread to use it
        });
```

Please let me know if the question needs further clarification

Comment: The pattern you need is modified producer-consumer. Producer adds 10 entities at the beginnning, customers tries to get entites. When 10 entities is got, rest of the threads wait for producer to put new items. When consumer job is end, it puts entity back to the producer stack.

Comment: @pwas that's object pooling, not producer consumer. Anyway, Parallel.For allows you to specify a thread initialization function to pass a unique object to each thread without locking or pooling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [concurrent collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) to store your 10 objects.
Each Worker will pull one data entity out, use it, and give it back. Te use of the concurrent collection is important, because in your scenario the normal one is not thread safe.

Like so:

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<DataEntity>();
// fill the queue with 10 items

Parallel.For(0, limit, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
    {
        DataEntity x;
        if(!queue.TryDequeue(out x))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        DoWork(i, x);
        queue.Enqueue(x);
    });
```

Or, if blocking needs to be provided, wrap the thing in a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Edit: Do *not* wrap it in a loop to keep waiting. Rather, use the BlockingCollection like this:

```
var entities = new BlockingCollection(new ConcurrentQueue<DataEntity>());

// fill the collection with 10 items

Parallel.For(0, limit, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
    {
        DataEntity x = entities.Take();
        DoWork(i, x);
        entities.Add(x);
    });
```

Comment: Simple concurrent collection is not enough IMHO. Yes, it is thread safe but it does not makes thread to wait for new items inside collection.

Comment: by the problem definition, there will be 10 workers and 10 data entities. It should be impossible for a worker to encounter an empty queue.

Comment: Correct as suggested by @pwas thread safety is not my major issue, but making thread wait for next available data entity is the main issue

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster This is interesting, you are throwing invalid operation exception as not getting an entity would not be a valid scenario or do you think I can wrap it in a do while loop, to keep waiting till it gets the entity

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster what you are trying to do is emulate an object pool like the one implemented in [Parallel Extensions Extras](https://github.com/ChadBurggraf/parallel-extensions-extras/blob/master/CoordinationDataStructures/ObjectPool.cs). You can't do this with a single ConcurrentQueue or a BlockingCollection.  Also, throwing on a perfectly valid situation like exhaustion of the pool is a *bad* idea

Comment: Well, your example implied that the data entities are not "processed away", but rather "reusable". Therefore you have 10 data entities and 10 workers. An entity gets put back before the worker is finished. Also you stated that "since the number of threads and data entity are same **starvation is not an issue**". So if I understood your question, the exception should never throw.

Comment: Blocking Collection was an important addition, which made it run as expected, ensuring each thread gets it's own unique data entity to work

Answer (score 7):

Use the overload of [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a thread local initialization function.

```
Parallel.For<DataEntity>(0, limit, 
    //will run once for each thread
    () => GetThreadLocalDataEntity(),

    //main loop body, will run once per iteration
    (i, loop, threadDataEntity) =>
    {
        DoWork(i, threadDataEntity);
        return threadDataEntity; //we must return it here to adhere to the Func signature.
    },

    //will run once for each thread after the loop
    (threadDataEntity) => threadDataEntity.Dispose() //if necessary
);
```

The main advantage of this method vs. the one you posted in the question, is that assignment of `DataEntity` happens once per thread, not once per loop iteration.

Comment: For my scenario where Data entity has to be reassigned, I still need to lock the code in GetThreadLocalDataEntity() and check which Data entity is available for use based on boolean, please correct me if I misunderstood. Also if I set MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10, then would it not call the method GetThreadLocalDataEntity() for 11th thread till the point one of thread completes the loop

Comment: @MrinalKamboj `GetThreadLocalDataEntity()` still has to lock. You do not have to use a boolean flag, you can, for example, put all your available `DataEntity` objects in a queue and dequeue one object for each thread. Regarding your second question, if you set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10`, then there will not be an 11th thread.

Comment: In fact my requirement is not to return anything, so is there an option without Func, since data entity gets utilized the loop and its done, it has nothing to do with return

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Couldn't you just return it anyways? There would be no effect.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The logic behind returning the object at the end of the loop is that it is passed into the next iteration of the loop as a parameter. In your case, it may seem meaningless, because `DataEntity` is a reference type (I assume). Were it a value type, like an `int`, it would be easier to see why it's necessary.

Comment: Is this how it works? The docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd783299(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests that the return in the body-invocation is the initial state of the next iteration or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Rouby Yes, that's exactly what I said, isn't it?

Comment: @Rotem Uhm yes of course, sorry I got this mixed up with a ForEach loop... :/